# The output of Gram - Schmidt process without normalizing

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

What happens if I don't do normalization during Gram - Schmidt algorithm, do I still get orthogonal vectors?

Comment: Show us what unnormalized formulas you use.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. If we start from a basis $\{\mathbf{v_i}\}$ , the G-S algorithm fix a first vector $\mathbf{u_1}=\mathbf{v_1}$ than the second vector can be constructed,without normalize $\mathbf{u_1}$, as :

$$\mathbf{u_2}=\mathbf{v_2}-\frac{\langle \mathbf{u_1},\mathbf{v_2} \rangle}{|\mathbf{u_1}|^2}\mathbf{u_1}$$
and this is orthogonal to $\mathbf{u_1}$.  Now we can use this vector for the successive step of the process, without normalize it and  so one, obtaining a set of orthogonal vectors $\{\mathbf{u_i}\}$.

Comment: But you normalized it by dividing the dot product by the length of u1, haven't you? Is it okay to insert a vector that is not normalized to compute Fourier coefficients?

Comment: No. To normalize $\mathbf{u_i}$ we have to calculate $\mathbf{u_i}/|\mathbf{u_i}|$. You can develop a function as a series of components with respect to any orthogonal basis, but usually the Fourier coefficients are the components with respect to an ortho-normal basis.

Comment: @mathew7k4b There is indeed some normalization going on to compute the projection of $\mathbf v_2$ onto $\mathbf u_1$, but you don’t have to keep the result.

Comment: @amd Thanks! I edit the typo

Comment: @EmilioNovati The second term still isn’t quite right, I believe. We want to *subtract* a multiple of $\mathbf u_1$ from $\mathbf v_2$ to get something orthogonal to $\mathbf u_1$, no?

Comment: yes! there was some confusion because on my paper I used a different notation for $u$ and $v$.... sorry :(

Comment: @EmilioNovati I hope you don’t mind my changing the $+$ to a $-$ to complete your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes then it's "just" not a normalized basis but still orthogonal.

Comment: But this is an answer. The OP asked "do I still get orthogonal vectors?" and this post answers "Yes." More detail would make this a *better* answer but this certainly is an answer. If you find that another answer is better, upvote it. I see no need to downvote or delete this answer.